# How to add input text in select option dropdown

Tags: javascript, select, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I would like to know how to add input text box to the select dropdown and use it as search filter in javascript.

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="trans">Trans</option>
    <option value="fund">Fund</option>
    <option value="insta">Insta</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [Try to use select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A thanks for reply, can use javascript not jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist):

> The HTML `<datalist>` element contains a set of  elements that represent the values available for other controls.

```html
<input list="select" name="select">
<datalist class="form-control" id="select">    
  <option value="Trans"/>
  <option value="Fund"/>
  <option value="Insta"/>
</datalist>
```

Comment: This is good, is it possible to restrict the input to the list items only?

Comment: @LazZiya, the input is already bound to the list items by linking the attribute *id* and *list*:)

Comment: but still the input can accept something else not defined in the datalist. right?

Comment: @LazZiya, now I got what you are meaning, for that we have to write additional code on the *input* event of the control:)

Comment: it's not working on the touch keyboard, why? should I send a keypress trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample from [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp):

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The search field */
#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* The search field when it gets focus/clicked on */
#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but have edited the code according to requirement, I have to add text input inside select, please review code

Comment: I reviewed your edit, it breaks the code and didn't work, it doesn't seem a practical way to deal with select input in this case

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using **select2**

Even the items get filtered

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```html
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is a plugin of jquery , So you have to link that url aswell

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()"class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown"class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text"placeholder="Search.." id="myInput"onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The search field */
#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image:url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* The search field when it gets focus/clicked on */
#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

JS:

```
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter =input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if(txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

[Working example here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_filter)

For more info, take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp

Comment: thanks but have edited the code according to requirement in `Laz Ziya post`, I have to add text input inside select, please review code