# Add search box to select dropdown

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create select dropdown with searchbox inside, how can I get this element to be inside the dropdown? I tried adding position relative and absolute. Even when I add top: 10px it doesn't move the element down 10px.

```css
select {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.search-box > input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

 input {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<form>

<select>
<option>Test</option>
<div class="search-box">
<input type="search" />
</div>
</select>

</form>
```

Comment: In this instance a `select` element isn't going to be your friend, I'd suggest looking at other options like a [custom dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp) of which there's loads of freebie examples out on the web or could utilize a UI framework with pre-built components that do it for you. Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add input text in select option dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702575/how-to-add-input-text-in-select-option-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

W3 Schools provides a great resource on how to create a dropdown menu in addition to a search bar to search for items in a [dropdown menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp). I think from there, you can implement the code into your program easily.